# Different Time Zone in Java

Tags: java

> How to get date based on the different time zone in java 1.7 ?

```
  AST
    EST
    CST
    MST
    PST
    AKST
    HAST
```

I have analysed the API. As per my understanding we need to pass date-format /city to get the time, Please refer the given below sample code to get the EST.

```
static DateTimeFormatter etFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy 'at' hh:mma 'ET'");
  static ZoneId etZoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
ZonedDateTime currentETime = currentISTime.withZoneSameInstant(etZoneId);
```

Do i need to pass the date-format and city to get the Time? Is there any generic way to get the Time based on the TimeZone ?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: ... and what result(s) did you get, and what result(s) did you expect? Different from what time zone exactly?

Comment: I would like get based on the Timezone not State based.

Comment: Based on the timezone i would like to get the time , let say  ETC  is timezone , i would like to get the ETC time.

Answer (score 1):

## True time zones

The 2-4 letter **abbreviations such as EST, IST, PST, CST, and so on are *not* time zones**. They merely give a clue about time zone, and indicate if in standard time or Daylight Saving Time (DST). They are not standardized. They are not even unique! Never use these, and stop thinking about them.

See Wikipedia for the list of true time zone names in the format of `Continent/Region`.

Your example code is nearly right.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

For that same moment as seen in UTC, extract a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

Adjust to India time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = instant.atZone( ZoneId.of ( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ) ;
```

To generate localized strings, use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…`.

This has all been discussed hundreds of times already on Stack Overflow. Search for more info.

## *ThreeTen-Backport*

If your Question is about how to perform such code while using the mentioned Java 7, the solution is the library from the *ThreeTen-Backport* project. You’ll find most of the *java.time* functionality with nearly identical API.